# MySQL How to insert four values into three column?

Tags: mysql

I have one TABLE

TABLE A

```
COL 1     COL 2    COL 3    COl 4
fname     lname    phone    email
```

And I want to **insert the name of firstname & lastname**
I mean name = fname + lname

My Query is

```
INSERT INTO `user_accounts` (`name`, `phone`, `email`)
SELECT  (`COL 1` +` COL 2`),  `COL 3` ,  `COL 4`  FROM  `TABLE A`
```

How can i insert with select statement?
Can i use the concat function?.

Comment: You have to use `CONCAT` function instead of `+` to concat field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `concat` to combine values from multiple columns.

```
INSERT INTO `user_accounts` (`name`, `phone`, `email`)
SELECT  concat( `COL 1`, ' ', `COL 2` ),  `COL 3` ,  `COL 4`  FROM  `TABLE A`
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea is correct, but MySQL uses `concat()` for string concatenation:

```
INSERT INTO `user_accounts`(`name`, `phone`, `email`)
    SELECT  concat(`COL 1`, ` COL 2`),  `COL 3`,  `COL 4`
    FROM  `TABLE A`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. We can combine using concat function like this.

```
INSERT INTO `table_name` (`name`, `phone`)
SELECT  concat( `COL 1`, ' ', `COL 2` ), concat( `COL 3` , ' ', `COL 4 `) FROM  `TABLE A`
```